# Speech to text using MsAzure Service Key

Tags: python-3.x, azure, speech-recognition

Hi I was trying to convert a large (.wav) audio file to a .txt file using the MsAzure Quick start GitHub Codes for Speech-to-text. I have pasted the codes below. These are producing neither result nor any error message.

```
def speech_recognize_continuous_from_file():
    """performs continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file"""
    # <SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=weatherfilename)

    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that stops continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    all_results = []
    def handle_final_result(evt):
        all_results.append(evt.result.text)

    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(handle_final_result)
    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    # Start continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)

    print("Printing all results:")
    print(all_results)
```

Can any body suggest me as to where I am going wrong. O am struggling a lot for last few days without any effective result.
Also I appreciate if any body can suggest how I can download and save the text file in a desired folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get write result content into a .txt file,try the test code below :

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import time

service_region = ''
speech_key=''
filename = 'D:/test.wav'
text_file_path = 'D:/temp/result.txt'

def speech_recognize_continuous_from_file():
    """performs continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file"""
    # <SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=filename)

    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that stops continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    all_results = []
    def handle_final_result(evt):
        all_results.append(evt.result.text)

    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(handle_final_result)
    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    # Start continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)

    print("writing result into txt file...")

    f = open(text_file_path, "w")
    for content in all_results:
        f.write(content)
    f.close()
    print("done.")

    print(all_results)
    

speech_recognize_continuous_from_file()
```

I save code to an individual .py file and run it directly, result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I got a similar result from .ipynb file. Can you please suggest how to get a general text file which is clear and readable.

Comment: So you want to write the result content into a .txt file? If so, I have updated my answer, pls accept it if it helps you.

Comment: Yes it worked. The text quality is 95% accurate. Is there any way to improve the text quality? Moreover the text file is spread over an infinite landscape. Is there any way to customize the paper width and inctrese the length instead of width being too wide.

Comment: @SALILRAY, yes , you can use custom speech to improve your speech to text service:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/custom-speech-overview.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consistent support to a new learner like me. I opened up the link and followed the instructions in sequence as delineated. I tried to do that with a new project by uploading my audio file (.wav format). I have the data stored in my OneDrive. It says invalid data. The uploading could not be done.   Moreover is there any block of Python Code available with the Custom Speech ? If so can you provide that link?   Thanks